# How to define mysqli connection in one php file and then use it on another file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am new to PHP and I`m using eclipse SDE to build a simple web application.

My Scenario is:

1. I have **index.php** page that include the login form (*2 textbox and Login Button*)
2. I have MySQL database that contains two tables: system_users & user_errors
3. whenever a user login successfully in the index.php page, this should redirect him to the **page1.php** and then retrieve his errors from the user_errors table and list them.

I want to achieve this in php.

Hereafter is my code:

index.php

```
    <html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssDesign.css">

<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
<?PHP

//MySQL Database Connect 
include 'mysql_connect.php';

$conn = MySQLConnection::getConnection();


// Create connection
//global $con;
//$con = new mysqli("192.168.0.2", "Invest", "NeeD$123","investmentprojects","3306");

if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,username,password,type FROM system_users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password='".$password."' ");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

if ($rows == 1) {
  header('Location: page1.php');
}       
else {
    print ("You're not a member of this site");
    }
}

//mysqli_close($conn);

?>

</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "index.php">

<table border="0" style="width:370px;border:0px;">
    <tr> 
        <td style ="width:30%;border:0px;">User</td>
        <td style ="width:70%;;border:0px;"><INPUT style ="width:100%;" TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="" NAME = "username"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td style ="width:30%;border:0px;">Password</td>
        <td style ="width:70%;border:0px;"><INPUT style ="width:100%;" TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="" NAME = "password"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td style ="width:30%;border:0px;"></td>
        <td align='right' style ="width:70%;border:0px;"><INPUT style ="width:30%;" TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login"> </td>
    </tr>

</table>


</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

page1.php

```
    <html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssDesign.css">

<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
</head>
<body>

<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="page1.php">

</FORM>

</body>
</html>

<?php

include 'mysql_connect.php';

$conn = MySQLConnection::getConnection();

$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql = "SELECT user_name,error_form,error_date,error_description " . 
        "FROM error_log WHERE username ='".$username."'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>User</th><th>Error Form</th><th>Error Date</th><th>Error Description</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row["user_name"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["error_form"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["error_date"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["error_description"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

//mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: where are you stuck? please explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make file connection.php with all that have tangence with mysql connection and after ad in each file where you use mysql query the line `include_once('connection.php');` or you can have  `include_once('some_folder\connection.php');`

If you are beginner you can use this mode to connect to DB

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
echo 'Connected successfully';

$res = mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: `include` might clone the connection, you should use `include_once` instead, and there's no need to add `()`

Comment: yes I observed that `()` is not necessary but I use it because for me is more clear. If you include one file once for make one page I think is not necessary to write once, because script end and after when new start it make new connection (or connection persist when script end???)

Comment: The connection will not persist (but recommended to disconnect it before ending the script), it's always better to use `include once` and it will work on single code page or N pages.


about the `()` I agree it is more clear and less confusing.

Comment: The code wrote by Mitch is semi- solution to my case since it generates the connection to the database. Howevere if this code saved in "connection.php" file then use "include(connection.php)" in my "index.php" file, then how I can pass the connection parameter to the mysqli_query function?

Comment: use that  `$link` and you will have `mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City")`