# How to declare mysqli connection as a global variable to use in functions

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I have create a test function to store user message in database and m using mysqli_connect for database connection. But when i create every new function i need to open mysqli connection in every new function. Its frustrated for me.
Have look at code

```
function abb() { $db  = new mysqli("localhost","root","","homeland");
```

`$dat = "insert into tbl_queryform(user_name,user_email,user_query)values('vijender Singh','vv@gmail.com','dds')";`

`$dat2 = mysqli_query($db, $dat); }`

`echo abb();`

Comment: Open the connection once in the main code, and pass `$db` as an argument to all the functions that need it. Or put `global $db;` in all those functions.

Comment: That question has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667825/how-to-define-mysqli-connection-in-one-php-file-and-then-use-it-on-another-file

Comment: Make a seperate connection class and make an instance of the class. Pass that object to every function in which you want to do some DB work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new file wherein your connection was declare then every time u=you need it just put `<?php include 'connection.php' ?>` near in your header
also it make your variables as $GLOBALS